# Two autocomplete function in a single input text

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete

I have two autocomplete function , that work fine for different textboxes , I want to add these two two autocomplete function values in single text box ,
1st function :

```
$(function () {
$(".AccountSuplier").autocomplete({
    source: '/AccAddAcount/AutoSearchSupplierAcc'
});
});
//that I used with textbox like this :
<input asp-for="Supplier" class="form-control AccountSuplier">
```

2nd function :

```
$(function () {
 $(".AutoEmplyee").autocomplete({
    source: '/EmpAddEmp/AutoSearchEmploy'
 });
 });

<input asp-for="Emplyee" class="form-control AutoEmplyee">
```

these two function work fine and give list of Supplier and Emplyees in different textboxes , Now I want to add these list in single textbox,

// code in controller for employ : (for Supplier is same like employ )

```
[HttpGet]
    public IActionResult AutoSearchEmploy()
    {
        var name = HttpContext.Request.Query["term"].ToString();

        PaginatedList<EmpAddEmploy> units = _EmpAddEmpRepo.GetItems("Name", SortOrder.Ascending, "", 1, 20);

        var data = units.Where(j => j.EmployeeName.ToLower().Contains(name.ToLower())).Select(j => j.EmployeeName);
        return Ok(data);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to manually combine the two queries.  Without testing, it would look something like this:

```
$(function () {
    $(".SupplierEmployee").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            let supplier = $.get("/AccAddAcount/AutoSearchSupplierAcc", {
                term: request.term
            });

            let employee = $.get("/EmpAddEmp/AutoSearchEmploy", {
                term: request.term
            });

            $.when(supplier, employee).done(function (data1, data2) {
                response(data1.concat(data2));
            });
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<input asp-for="Supplier" class="form-control SupplierEmployee">
```

Comment: it only show success , success in the list .

Comment: You will need to look at what is returned from those calls and combine appropriately.  If you do a `$.ajax` call with GET, it will return `[data, status, xhrObject]` I believe, so you would need to combine the two `data` objects.

Answer (score 0):

I try this but it work only for 1st class and give list of Supplier

```
<input asp-for="User" class="form-control AccountSuplier AutoEmplyee">
```